# I keep getting an error when installing homebrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, homebrew

I need to install homebrew on my Mac and order to use Ruby on rails. I have  Tried about a dozen times and I keep getting an error and I have unseen unsuccessfully resolved the error.
When I try to install it it will say permission denied updating files 100%, done. And then it says installation successful. When I go back to double check to see if it was installed it says no such job. What am I doing wrong?

Tried about a dozen times and I keep getting an error and I have unseen unsuccessfully resolved the error.

Comment: try this command sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*

Comment: Please read the following two articles: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Your question lacks diagnostic information that would enable others to provide assistance, including the exact commands you run and the exact error messages you receive. Please update your post to include those details by copying and pasting the text into your post (do not post screenshots) and then formatting it using markdown as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.